# Uploading a file with a "-" removes the part before the "-"

Tags: html, google-chrome, file-upload

I am experiencing a weird bug when uploading a file that has a "-" in the middle of its name.

Exemple :

> 1. I upload a file name 1- Copy.png to the server, but the file.name for this  one becomes only "Copy.png"

Code:

Input :

```
<td colspan=3 style="padding-left:12px;">
      Attach File2: <br>
      <input name=ATTACHMENT1 type=FILE size=56 style="color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">
</td>
```

Save :

```
 INSERT INTO PT5_FILE(
        FILE_ID, FILE_TICKET_ID, FILE_TIME, 
        FILE_NAME, FILE_SIZE, FILE_DATA)
      VALUES(
        Local.FILE_ID, Local.TICKET_ID, Local.Now, 
        attach1.name, attach1.size, attach1.data);
```

It seems that the server strips the first part before I can even access it.

It only happens in chrome, it works fine in ie.

Comment: What language? What's your code look like?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Updated the op

Comment: I would add the flavor of SQL you're using to your tags - SQL Server?